# jquery mobile width of a collapsible-set on a web page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible-set which works correctly on a narrow webpage representing a mobile device. When I increase the width of the page the set expands correctly - until a background object springs up from behind the top button. This covers whatever is normally above the collapsible-set in the display.

This change seems to happen when the page width is 690 px (?)

It means the display is as intended on an iphone but corrupts on an iPad.

Any suggestions about how to stop this happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you post the corresponding source code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. It was not the collapsible-set but a slider higher on the page. When I removed the slider the collapsible-set expanded correctly without the background object appearing. I still don't know why the interference was occurring but I will investigate that later.